# Jquery Dialog box button text mouse over cursor change

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using jquery version 1.8.3 dialog box control, with two buttons in it.

```
$('<div></div>').appendTo('body').html().dialog({
            modal: true,  zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
            width: '450px', resizable: false,stack: false,
            dialogClass: 'closeDialog',
            buttons: {
                "YesButton" : {
         text: "Yes",
                id: "yesbtnid",               
                } ,
                "NoButton" : {
                text: "No",
                id: "nobtnid",               
                }
            },
            open: function() {              
                $(this).closest('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-button').removeClass("ui-button").addClass("btnHeightWidth");
                });
               }
        });
```

i have added my css class to the buttons,my css class is

```
.btnHeightWidth
{
    width:100px;
    height:43px;
    font-Weight:bold;
    font-size:16px;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#FFEEE9E2', endColorstr='#FFC5BFB5');
    behavior: url(border-radius.htc);
    border-radius: 11px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 11px;
   cursor:pointer;
}
```

The problem is when i mouseover on the button text, "Yes" or "No" the mouse cursor changes from hand to pointer, how to make it constant as hand.

Comment: when i remove my css class the mouse cursor remains to be hand, so i suspect the problem is in my custom css class.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle.net?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CC9gM/3/

Comment: Am running this using IE8

Comment: @Dwellerincellar Just to understand your problem, when you hover on the buttons the mouse changes to the default one right? you want the hand pointer instead?

Comment: ya to clarify the problem statement, on mouse over on button the mouse cursor changes to hand, however when the mouse moves over the button text ie either "Yes" or "No" in this case the mouse cursor changes to default .

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane button.ui-state-hover.ui-widget .ui-button-text{
      cursor:pointer;
}
```

Key is to be specific for applying styles. You can either modify the styles in jquery-ui.css or create more specific selectors. You can also use `!important` but that' not suggested.

Also, you don't need to remove any class from buttons using jQuery.
I updated your code to:

```
$(this).closest('.ui-dialog').find('.ui-button').addClass("btnHeightWidth");
```

Updated code: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/CC9gM/8/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i added the class to my css but it doesnt reflect the change in IE8, however in other browsers its working fine.

Comment: Well, I can only suggest to add "!important" in the css rule in case of IE. If you can share your more html and css, then probably I can suggest something else by looking at it

Comment: I tried !important as well, but it dint work. Am using the same code as given in jsfiddle link given above.

Comment: Let me try this on IE8.

Comment: I couldn't try on IE8. Windows 7 doesn't allow IE8 installation. Anyway, try removing that filter from css rule.